# how to intent JSONArray?

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-intent, kotlin

I use json data in Fragment.I want to intent nested jsonArray **genre_ids** for another activity but I tried some solutions and it doesn't work.What should I do now?

**HomeFragment**

```
    for (i in 0 until tur!!.length()) {
                                    val film = Movie()
                                    var jsonObj = tur.getJSONObject(i)
                                    film.title = jsonObj.getString("title")
                                    film.releaseDate = jsonObj.getString("release_date")
                                    film.posterPath = jsonObj.getString("poster_path")
                                    film.voteAverage = jsonObj.getString("vote_average")
                                    film.overView = jsonObj.getString("overview")

                                    film.genreIds = jsonObj.getJSONArray("genre_ids").toString() 
<br/>
   **MovieDetailActivity**

                    var baslik = intent.extras.getString("title")
                    tvDetayBaslik.text = baslik
                    var resim = intent.extras.getString("image")
                    var url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"
                    var poster = Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(url + resim).into(imgPosterDetay)
                    var tarih = intent.extras.getString("date")
                    tvDetayTarih.text = tarih
                    var puan = intent.extras.getString("point")
                    if (puan=="0.0"){
                        tvDetayPuan.text="Puan yok"
                    }else {
                        tvDetayPuan.text = puan.toString()
                    }
                    var aciklama = intent.extras.getString("description")
                    if (aciklama == "") {
                        tvDetayOverview.text = "Açıklama Yapılmamıştır."
                    } else {
                        tvDetayOverview.text = aciklama
                    }
                         var turId=intent.extras.getString("id")
                         tvGenre.text= turId.toString()
```

Comment: convert your jsonarray to its string value, put it inside an intent as extra, receive it in your next activity. finally, put it back in your jsonarray object.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave data as objects then use PutParcelableArrayList

Implement Parcelable first on your element in arraylist.

shoort example :

```
ArrayList<ZAP> zapotrzebowania = new ArrayList<ZAP>();
```

fill your array and send as parcelable.
 then add to your bundle.

```
datatodoc.putParcelableArrayList("dokument", zapotrzebowania);
```

Answer (score 0):

For passing JSONArray from one activity to another activity, you need to convert the JSONArray into the string and then put it into the Intent as extras. On the receiver side, get the string data from the extras and convert it into the JSONArray.

About passing nested jsonArray genre_ids to another activity, there are two options:

1. Either iterated through the JSON data, collect the genre_ids into the either arrays or ArrayList. Pass it to the destination activity when data is ready. On receiver side, get the data and display it.
2. OR pass the complete JSON object and iterate through the JSON data as option #1 given above.